# fig-width has no effect in a quarto document

Tags: python, quarto

Consider the following code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
---

```{python}
#| echo: false
#| fig-align: center
#| fig-width: 1cm

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2]
y = [2, 3]

plt.plot(x,y)
```
````

The parameter `fig-width` has no effect whatever the chosen width.

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

You can also use [`set_figwidth`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_figwidth) from `matplotlib` to control the plot figure sizes generated by `matplotlib`.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
engine: jupyter
---

```{python}
#| echo: false
#| fig-align: center

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plot = plt.figure()
plot.set_figwidth(2)
plot.set_figheight(3)

x = [1, 2]
y = [2, 3]

plt.plot(x,y)

```
````

---

[image: plot sized with matplotlib options]

---

Try with integer number 2 instead of `2cm`. (It works when with `engine: knitr`)

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
engine: knitr
---

```{python}
#| echo: false
#| fig-align: center
#| fig-width: 2


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2]
y = [2, 3]

plt.plot(x,y)

```
````

Comment: Thanks, @shafee, for your answer. That works when one uses `engine: knitr`, but unfortunately, not with `engine: jupyter`.

Comment: well, I have tried `knitr` seeing your question with `r-reticulate` virtualenv : )

Comment: Ok yes, I have reproduced the issue with `engine: jupyter` and I think, neither of the `fig-align` and `fig-width` has effects.

Comment: You are right, @shafee: `r-reticulate` is a virtualenv. In my case, with `engine: jupyter`, `fig-align` works, but not `fig-width`. I guess it is a bug, and I am going to report.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right actually, `fig-align` is working as intended. and, well, in the meantime, I guess you can use `matplotlib` specific` options.